# How to handle Table row selected changed?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

How to handle row selected changed event for a table using Blazor?
I tried handling @onchange as well as @onselectionchange.
The syntax for the table looks like this:

`<table class="table" @onchange="@this.SelectionChanged">`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your event binding doesn't work because the `table` element does not emit `change` events.

Instead, you could add an input element (for example a checkbox) inside your table rows. You can then handle row selection changes by adding your event binding to the input elements.

Read more on the HTMLElement change event in [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event).

Comment: Good point. Thats for the insight. I started going towards adding a OnMouseUp on the Row element in the body. THis might work.

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Although this may work, it is generally a better practice to use the appropriate elements for what you want to achieve. In this case, a checkbox or maybe a button would be better (for things like accessibility and cross-browser compatibility). Just some advice ;-).

Answer (score 1):

You can use Onclick in the row:

```
  <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Forecasts)
            {
              
                <tr class="@item.Clase" @onclick="@(() => DoSomething(item))">
                    <td>@item.Date</td>
                    
                    <td>@item.TemperatureC</td>
                    <td>@item.TemperatureF</td>
                    <td>@item.Summary</td>
                </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
```

and create a Dosomething to receive the item